# routing node.js and express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm having a problem routing in express 4. I was following the example, but it isn't loading. I'm just getting a spinning wheel.

How do you do routing in express version 4?

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');

var http = require('http');
var app = express();


app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


var port = (process.env.PORT || process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 5000);

app.use('/birds', require('./controller/bird'));

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    //res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    //res.end('Hello World!\n');
}).listen(port);



console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:'+port);
```

bird.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// middleware specific to this router
router.use(function timeLog(req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time: ', Date.now());
  next();
});
// define the home page route
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Birds home page');
});
// define the about route
router.get('/about', function(req, res) {
  res.send('About birds');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling the `app.listen()` function. Instead of the `http.createServer` one, you should invoke the Express function.

Please, take a look at a basic [example](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html).

Relevant code:

```
app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

**Edit:** as [slebetman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/167735/slebetman) wrote in the comment, the more general way for it is:

```
http.createServer(app).listen(port, function(){ 
    console.log('now listening on port ' + port);
});
```

Comment: Alternatively he could have called `http.createServer(app).listen(port)`. This more general method is useful because you can use it with `https.createServer(conf,app).listen(port)` if you need to support https